# Is there a way to test if a cell contains any kind of visible formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have built a function that will return the next available row that has no data in it based on a column letter provided. In this case the data must be continuous in that column so if there is gaps in the rows then I know this wont work. There is an optional argument called Format that if set to 1 will assume formatted cells are considered used and wont accept it as empty. This is what I have

```
// @param {txt} SheetName   : The name of the sheet are testing on.
// @param {txt} Column      : The column letter that we are checking for a next row in
// @param {int} Format      : Optional Boolean Value, when testing for the next available row does a formatted cell count as a used cell IE the cell has a fill, has a border, 1 = yes, 0 = no (default)
// @returns {number}        : return the next available row number.
function getNextAvailableRowInColumn(SheetName, Column, Format = 0){

  var ColValues = ss.getRange(SheetName+'!'+Column+'1:'+Column).getValues(); // This should evaluate to .getRange("Invoices!A1:A");
  var NextAvailableRow = ColValues.filter(String).length +1; 
  // We add 1 so we get the next available row and not the last row with data
  
if (Format) {  
 while (THIS CELL HAS FORMATING) {
    NextAvailableRow +1;
 }
}
return NextAvailableRow;
  
}
```

So based on this function above everything works great and the logic is sound. Once we find that next available row that does not have any data in it but we don't know if it's empty of formatting (if we have bit set) so we have test the cell and if it has visible formatting go down one row and test again and just keep going down the rows till we find a cell void of formatting.

Question is, how do I test for the "THIS CELL HAS FORMATING"? How would I test to see if a cell had ANY kind of visible formatting done to it like a border added to it, highlighting done to it? I do not care about non visible formatting like bold, or underline or font color is set.

Comment: How would this test for visible elements like fill or border properties?

Comment: Please read the question fully before answering and asking followups. Follow the logic and what is being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if a cell has formatting using runs from the `getRichTextValue` method.

```
function cellHasFormatting(address = "A1") {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(address);
  var runs = cell.getRichTextValue().getRuns();
  for (let r=0; r<runs.length; r++) {
    const style = runs[r].getTextStyle();
    if (style.isBold() || style.isItalic() || style.isUnderline()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this function tests for non visible formating and I don't care about that because the first test tests for data in the cell if there is no data there then things like bold italic or underline will not be visible so it's really no point looking for it. I want to test for viable formating like fill color and borders and anything else someone can think of that visible formating you can do to a cell. I'm guessing I could just adjust your function above to test for border value or fill value I was just curious if there was a proper way of doing this with built in functions.